# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript

```
function f1<T extends {[prop: string]: any}}>(a: T = {}) {
    console.log(a)
}
```

> Error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.

im trying to give a a default value. im not trying to give T a default type.

I'm not sure what is the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider  the following example

```
type A = { [prop: string]: any };
type B = { [prop: string]: any; prop1: string };
```

Does type `B` extend type `A`? Yes!

But the following will not work

```
let a: A = {};
let b: B = a; // Error
```

It's clear that type `A` misses required property `prop1`, so variable `a` is not assignable to variable `b`.

The same issue is with your function. When you do

```
function f1<T extends { [prop: string]: any }>(a: T = {}) {
    console.log(a);
}
```

Compiler says that object `{}` is not assignable to type `T`. If this worked, you could do

```
f1<B>();  // a will equal to {} and misses required prop1
```

This may not look like error, as inside `f1` you only know that `T extends { [prop: string]: any }` and know nothing about `prop1`. But consider if you want return `T`:

```
function f1<T extends { [prop: string]: any }>(a: T = {}): T {
    console.log(a);
    return a;
}
```

If this code would work it would introduce a bug

```
let bb: B = f1<B>();  // Here bb will be equal to empty object
let s: string = bb.prop1;  // Compiler will not show error, as it thinks that bb has prop1 of type string. But in reality it is undefined.
```

So there are following solutions to consider:

1. Remove all generics. Type `{ [prop: string]: any }` is generic by itself so it may suit your needs

   ```
   function f1(a: { [prop: string]: any } = {}) {
       console.log(a);
       return a;
   }
   ```
2. Make `a` fully optional. In this case `a` may equal to `undefined` and compiler would know about it.

   ```
   function f1<T extends { [prop: string]: any } = {}>(a?: T) {
       console.log(a);
   }
   ```

   If you return `a` compiler will tell you that you should either return union type (with `undefined`) or check in function body that `a` is not `undefined`.
3. Worst case from my point of view is to use type cast as already suggested

   ```
   function f1<T extends { [prop: string]: any }>(a: T = {} as T) {
       console.log(a);
   }
   ```

   But be careful and don't forget that you can miss some required properties in this case.

Comment: I understand it now. I was thinking the wrong way around. I have been using generics in C# for years, and sometimes I still get confused about the inheritance direction. You are absolutely right: you cannot simply assign a value of a certain base type (in this case value `{}`) to a binding of a (possibly) derived type (in this case `a: T`). Thanks for the clarification.